# Collating multiple knockout subscriptions into a single notification?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

In knockout you can do the following:

`myObservable.subscribe(function(newValue){ doSomething(); });`

Now if I have multiple observables I want to subscribe on I could do:

`myObservable1.subscribe(function(){ doSomething(); });
myObservable2.subscribe(function(){ doSomething(); });`

However this can get a bit unsightly when I have lots of subscribes and also if you wanted to throttle the update mechanism currently you would have to do it per subscription.

So is there a way for me to wrap them all in some way? i.e.

`ko.subscribeToMany(myObservable1, myObservable2)
   .throttle(500)
   .subscribe(function(){ doSomething() });`

I have a scenario where I basically want to refresh a chart based upon changes, and its quite resource intensive, so I was hoping that rather than having to subscribe to each dynamic bit of data I could collate them into a single computed style subscription and then from there throttle that individual subscription as other subscriptions may want to be notified straight away without a delay/throttle.

So is the above possible with Knockout?

Comment: Do you need the `newValue` parameter or just want to get notified?

Comment: In this scenario I do not care about the newValue, I just want to know when a change to the underlying data has occurred. However I am sure others in this situation may need to have access to the observables that had changed, but lets not complicate this one just yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick implemenation could be the following:

```
ko.obsgroup = function() {

    var groupManager = {};    
    var observables = [];

    var throttle = 0;
    var throttleTimeout;

    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        observables.push(arguments[i]);
    }

    groupManager.throttle = function(duration) {
        throttle = duration;
        return groupManager;
    };

    groupManager.subscribe = function(handler) {

        function throttledHandler(val) {
            if(throttle > 0) {
                if(!throttleTimeout) {
                    throttleTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                        throttleTimeout = undefined;
                        handler(val);
                    }, throttle);
                }
            } else {
                handler(val);
            }
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            observables[i].subscribe(throttledHandler);
        }
        return groupManager;
    };

    return groupManager;
};
```

### Usage:

```
var vm = {
    v1: ko.observable(0),
    v2: ko.observable(0),
    v3: ko.observable(0),
    log: ko.observable(0)
};

ko.obsgroup(vm.v1, vm.v2, vm.v3)
  .throttle(1000)
  .subscribe(function(val) {
      vm.log('changed: ' + Date.now());
  });

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

#

#### Demo: [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/sokjnuqy/3/)

Comment: Ah so you are basically wrapping the subscriptions externally then only delegating after a certain throttle. Will give you the answer for now unless someone comes up with a better approach.

Comment: That's how throttling value updates is done in knockout also. But, here the throttling is applied to change notifications.